# Как называется человек, посещающий курсы?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, терминология

Как называется человек, посещающий курсы, например, шитья?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Есть слова *курсант* и *курсист*, но они пропахли нафталином (курсант стал обозначать учащегося военной школы или военного училища). Лучше, пожалуй, сказать *слушатель курсов (кройки и шитья)*, а еще привычней звучит *обучающийся на курсах (кройки и шитья)*.

Дополнение. Нашел в Нацкорпусе также учащихся курсов и учащихся на курсах:

> В «Материалах о занятиях **учащихся курсов** по сольному пению» ― учебных журналах, которые вела Татаринова и, видимо, предоставляла в качестве отчетов Станиславскому, ― сказано: [Алиса Коонен: начало пути (2003) // «Театральная жизнь», 2003.08.25]
>
> Тогда им будут розданы правила для **учащихся на курсах** и расписание лекций. [Л. А. Чарская. Мой принц (1915)]

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! А если, к примеру, эти самые "курсы" называются "Школа ...... ", тогда как?

Comment: Думаю, *учащийся "Школы кройки и шитья"* звучит нормально. Но *слушатель* тоже допустимо.

Comment: У нас рядом есть курсы повышения квалификации. Преподаватель предпочитает говорить _слушатели_ (более официально) либо _обучающиеся_. Хотя с шитьем (более практический курс) _слушатели_, кажется, звучит не совсем точно.